# ListView search not recognizing word after a symbol

Tags: android, listview, search

I have an issue. Some of my string entries have parenthesis [ie. Bob (Robert)]. and if I would search for "Robert", it is not found. Is there something I can do, add or change to allow it to find words in parenthesis, brackets, after dashes, etc.

My code is below. This from an androidhive tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/. I have modified the code for my purposes but I am showing the androidhive code. How can get the search to see words in parenthesis or other symbols?

```
package com.androidhive.androidlistviewwithsearch; 


import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.HashMap; 

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.text.Editable; 
import android.text.TextWatcher; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.ListView; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    // List view 
    private ListView lv; 

    // Listview Adapter 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; 

    // Search EditText 
    EditText inputSearch; 

    // ArrayList for Listview 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        // Listview Data 
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE", 
                                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800", 
                                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"}; 

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view); 
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch); 

        // Adding items to listview 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products); 
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); 

        /** 
         * Enabling Search Filter 
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { 
                // When user changed the Text 
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 
            } 

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, 
                    int arg3) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

            } 

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You didn't post the most important bit of your code: where the filtering is done!

Comment: That is the main code. All of it and it works great except for my issue. There is an xml file for how the listview will look and is laid out. There is another xml file for the layout which consists of an editbox and listview tags. Follow the link to see how everything looks, but what I posted is the all the coding for the search.

Comment: Very nice tutorial here http://tech-papers.org/android-listview-search-using-filter/

Answer (score 1):

A custom filter with default adapter can be implemented like this:

```
final ArrayAdapter<Brand>[] itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter[]{new ArrayAdapter<Brand>(WatchoutKPIActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, brands)};
            listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter[0]);
            EditText searchText = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.search_text);
            searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {

                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                              int arg2, int arg3) {

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    itemsAdapter[0] =
                            new ArrayAdapter<Brand>(WatchoutKPIActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filterBrand(arg0.toString(),brands, itemsAdapter[0]));
                    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter[0]);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see now. The problem is that the default filter that is provided is `ArrayFilter` (you can see the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.ArrayFilter)). This class assumes that you want a prefix search, so you will never match anything that is after the start of the text; "ob" won't match "Bob".  The only way to get the behavior you want is to extend your `ArrayAdapter` to provide your own implementation of the `getFilter()` method and return your new custom filter that matches text how you want.

Comment: actually "ob" will come up with "bob", this is not the issue. The issue is if the list item is "Bob (Robert)" and I type "r" or "rob" or even "robert", it won't show the entry "Bob (Robert)". If I type a partial entry or even the last letters of an entry (ex "ob") it will find the entry, but If I put in a partial entry of something in parenthesis then it won't find it.

Comment: Right, did you look at the code I linked? The only comparison that is made is `string.startsWith()` (to the whole text and to each token after the string is split by spaces). You must implement your own filtering logic if you want to do a "contains" type search, as I stated.